# Draw single pixel line in html5 canvas

Tags: html, canvas

When i try to draw single pixel black line with the following code:

```
    context.strokeStyle = '#000'; 
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(x1, y1); 
    context.lineTo(x2, y2);
    context.lineWidth = 1;
    context.stroke();
    context.closePath();
```

I have more then one pixel line with gray border. How to fix it?

Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/z4VJq/

Comment: is there maybe an css styling on your canvas ?

Comment: @EvilP see example in my post

Comment: See this: http://jsfiddle.net/z4VJq/5/; I've zoomed the canvas by 5x to help you see what's going on.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Call your function with these coordinates instead: `drawLine(30,30.5,300,30.5);`. Try it in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z4VJq/2/).

The problem is that your color will be at an edge, so the color will be halfway in the pixel above the edge and halfway below the edge. If you set the position of the line in the middle of an integer, it will be drawn within a pixel line.

This picture (from the linked article below) illustrates it:

[image]

You can read more about this on [Canvas tutorial: A lineWidth example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Applying_styles_and_colors#A_lineWidth_example).

Comment: but if you made `lineWidth` little bigger you will see blur `context.lineWidth =10;`

Comment: @mgraph: True, you are right, you get a blur with `lineWidth = 10`, because it's an even number, but not if you set `lineWidth = 11`, and that is how it should be.

Comment: So I added 0.5 to X and the result is still the same.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `context.translate(.5,.5);` to offset everything by half a pixel. Its easy way for fix your problem

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
var context1 = canvas.getContext('2d');
context1.strokeStyle = '#000'; 
context1.beginPath();
context1.moveTo(10, 5); 
context1.lineTo(300, 5);
context1.stroke();

var canvas2 = document.getElementById("canvas2");
var context2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');
context2.translate(.5,.5);
context2.strokeStyle = '#000'; 
context2.beginPath();
context2.moveTo(10, 5); 
context2.lineTo(300, 5);
context2.stroke();
```

```html
<div><canvas height='10' width='300' id='canvas1'>Обновите браузер</canvas></div>
<div><canvas height='10' width='300' id='canvas2'>Обновите браузер</canvas></div>
```