# HTML5 Canvas line anti aliasing inconsistency

Tags: html, canvas, 2d, antialiasing, rectangles

I have a situation where anti-aliasing is not perfect under Chrome and Firefox, but perfect in Internet Explorer 9.

The code, simplified is:

```
ctx.scale(zoom, zoom);
for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i++){
    ctx.fillRect(i*10, 0, 1, 1000); 
}
```

As I zoom out using scaling, instead of the lines blurring evenly into a solid shaded square, it goes from 1) consistent lines, to 2) uneven looking lines, to 3) unevenly shaded square.

Is there any way I can fix number 2? I've fixed number 3 by simply drawing a shaded square instead of all the lines. I had an idea, and that was to blur the lines or something like that. Maybe that would work? (Probably more intensive on processing though?)

Thanks

Comment: Please note that the canvas pixel center is 0.5 so try adding +0.5 to your coordinate. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9311835/315168