# Blurry div after css transform/transition

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

Working on a content slider, following the directions of this demo http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/sliding/

However with mine, I've noticed that my content, in this case a few divs, become slightly blurry after the css transition is done. Tested it in the latest versions of Firefox, Safari, and Opera and it works perfectly fine. So the blur is only occurring in Chrome (I'm on 22.0.1229.79)

Any ideas as to what this might be, or how to fix it?

http://jsfiddle.net/SYYhS/5/

Comment: Hmmm - I'm in Chrome 21.0.1180.89/Mac, and am not seeing the issue. The boxes appear fine to me after the transition. Can you post a screengrab of what you're seeing?

Comment: @chipcullen Also looks fine in **Firefox 15.0.1**.

Comment: Chrome 22.0.1229.79/Windows here and I can definitely see it. I think this has to do with pixel edges, but it seems I can't find the article I read...

Comment: Here you go - check this SO thread and see if it helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311428/draw-single-pixel-line-in-html5-canvas -- but maybe this is only with canvas...

Comment: @chipcullen here's a comparison. It's not extremely different, but the blur is definitely there. http://d.pr/i/jOsd

Comment: @JackArrgon I see what you mean - but on my system the edges are crisp. I'm on a Mac - are you looking at this in Windows, as Anders is? I'm not sure what would be OS-specific about the transition effect, though.

Comment: @chipcullen I'm on a Mac. I don't know, but I somehow don't think it would be OS-specific considering it doesn't happen on other browsers. My guess right now would be it's the version of Chrome (22.0.1229.79) which both Anders and I have. Perhaps a bug of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

Problem in half of pixel.

Try: `transform: translate(-50%, -51%);` Or, try to set the div dimensions with even number.

It will work!