# Setting true colors to a canvas border stroke?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I have this simple code of setting rectangle.

I'm stroking its border with a black color.

However , I dont see any black here but gray.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>

<script>
function draw()
{
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.strokeRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.w, rect.h);
}
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
var rect = {
    x: 10,
    y: 10,
    w: 40,
    h: 100
};
draw();
</script>

</html>
```

**Question :**

What am I doing wrong and how can I set the color to be as I define ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Draw single pixel line in html5 canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311428/draw-single-pixel-line-in-html5-canvas)

Comment: Duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311428/draw-single-pixel-line-in-html5-canvas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a canvas line, it will make a line passing through the points you declared, and with a width of `lineWidth`. If the line is between 2 pixels (for example when you create a line passing through borders, meaning you choose integer values for x and y) it will dissolve the color to balance the 2 pixels your line is crossing, in this case 50% to the pixel on the left, and 50% to the pixel on the right, resulting in a greyish color.
Adding `.5` to your x and y makes the line always stay in 1 pixel

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>

<script>
function draw()
{
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.strokeRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.w, rect.h);
}
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
var rect = {
    x: 10.5,
    y: 10.5,
    w: 40,
    h: 100
};
draw();
</script>

</html>
```

If you run the snippet you'll see that the lines are straight black, and occupying only 1 pixel in width. I just added .5 to your x and y