# How to get true 1-pixel width black color line in p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js, blend-mode

The p5.js [line()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/line) function does not seem to be able to draw a true 1-pixel wide black line. (Or any other color.)

- `strokeWeight` is 1 pixel, but the resulting line is 2 pixels wide.
- `color` is black with no transparency, but the resulting color is gray.

`blendMode()` seems to have something to do with the funny results above. I tried `REPLACE`, but it didn't have the effect I expected. (Only the last shape seems to survive?)

**How can I draw a 1-pixel wide line in p5.js with the "true" stroke color?** Is this a limitation of the underlying `canvas` element?

A simple p5.js demo is included in the snippet below. This problem can also be seen in official p5.js examples:

- [No Loop](https://p5js.org/examples/structure-no-loop.html) (Should be white line on black background.)
- [strokeWeight()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/strokeWeight) (All lines should be black.)

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 100);
  
  background(200);
    
  stroke(0,0,0, 255); // Black color, no transparancy.
  
  strokeWeight(1);   // Default
  line(20, 20, 380, 20);
  
  strokeWeight(2);   // 2
  line(20, 40, 380, 40);
  
  strokeWeight(4);   // Thicker
  line(20, 60, 380, 60); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/p5.min.js"></script>


Zoom in and verify pixels/colors with color picker: <input type=color>
```

Comment: Not quite p5, but essentially the same concept: [Draw single pixel line in html5 canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311428/draw-single-pixel-line-in-html5-canvas)

Comment: p5.js uses webgl to draw the shapes. In fact, a line primitive is rendered. Specify coordinates in the "center" of the fragments (pixels). Unfortunately, that depends on your system's DPI scale.

Comment: I think you have to use context.translate(.5,.5); for your canvas context

Comment: Oh, [translate()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/translate) is much nicer than adding 0.5 to all my coordinates! @PetePearl